# Mathematical game with numbers

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

We invented a mathematical game, which i am going to explain here.

---

The first player choose a natural number, lets call it $n$ (if you play it for real, you must choose a sufficiently big number so the game is interested).

The second player remove a square ${k_1}^2$ from that number, so that $n-{k_1}^2>0$.

The first player remove again a square ${k_2}^2$ and so on until $$n-\sum_i {k_i}^2=1.$$

The player who gets to $1$ win.

---

This is the algorithm (Sagemath) we used to model when the second player is winning :

```
def strat(n,L=[]):
l=len(L)+1
while l<n:
    suivant=True  
    i=1
    while i^2<l and suivant:
        if L[l-i^2-1]==0:
            L.append(1)
            l+=1
            suivant=False
        i+=1
    if suivant:
        L.append(0)
        l+=1
return L
```

---

We already proved that for a given number $n$ either player 1 or player 2 wins. We also proved that winning integers for the second player will tend to $1$ when $n$ tends to infinity.

We think this proportion can be modeled by $$p(n)=1-\frac 1{\sqrt n}.$$

We would like to prove these statements without heuristics arguments.

Finally, we would love to have a close formula to determine which are the winning integers for the second player.

---

What progresses did we make thanks to the comments ?

It seems that this question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377898/prime-numbers-and-a-two-player-game), with square instead of prime numbers mainly.

One can then wonder for a more general result about this kind of question. If $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$ such that $E$ has a density of $0$, we can play the same game with picking numbers of $E$. In our case, we took $E:=\{n^2,\ n\in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}\}$.

Comment: Why would the first player ever choose a number other than $3$? (or $1$, if he's allowed to do that and it counts as an immediate win for him)

Comment: Because the whole point of the game is to choose a sufficiently big number so the game is interested

Comment: @ElioJOSEPH You can address Henning's point by saying that $n$ is chosen either by an arbiter or by player 2, or by saying that these people play for fun. I'm not clear on who wins: if the number is $5$ and I say $2^2=4$ so $5-4=1$, do I win or do I lose? Either variant of the game is interesting, because if this is a loss for me, you think about 'forcing' the opponent to arrive at $1$.

Comment: I edited to take account on @HenningMakholm remark.

Comment: If you take the number $5$, and you say that, you win because you have obtained $1$. But you're right, either variant are the same.

Comment: @ElioJoseph Thank you. What do you mean when you say that there is a winning strategy for either of the players? As I understand the terms, given some $n$, if both players play optimally, *either* player 1 wins, or player 2, but there is no such thing as a winning strategy for both at the same time. Did you mean that there exist both numbers for which 1 wins, and numbers for which 2 wins?

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen Sorry for my poor english, i meant either player 1 wins or player 2 by playing optimally. I will edit, and thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @ElioJoseph Pas de probleme! Je voulais être sûr que j'ai bien compris ;)

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen Merci :) Si tu as une idée de solution, même partielle, ne m'oublies pas !

Comment: Note that the statement that for any fixed number either player one has a winning strategy or player two does is just [Zermelo's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_theorem_(game_theory)).

Comment: Also, when you say you've "proved" that the asymptotic density of winning numbers for player 2 is 1, do you just mean you have numerical evidence for that?

Comment: [This other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1377898/287040) deals with the same problem, except the numbers are primes instead of squares (and you must end at 0, not at 1, which doesn't matter). One may well ask this question for primes, squares, cubes, semiprimes, or some other infinite set with asymptotic density $0$. I would be interested in this more general result.

Comment: @JackM I didn't really prove that the asymptotic density of winning numbers for player 2 is $1$, i think i have something i would be able to turn into an actual proof. If you have something solid, don't hesitate to post it.

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen It seems related in some way to the other question indeed, i will edit to take account of that remark, and also to ask about a more general result.

Comment: I believe the sequence http://oeis.org/A224839 is relevant.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you so much, this sequence seems to be exactly the sequence of wins for player 2 !

Comment: @ElioJoseph, I thought so.  The shifted sequence http://oeis.org/A030193 should also be of interest; it has a couple of references.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks for the other sequence, but i don't really understand the connection with this problem...

Comment: @ElioJoseph, it's really the exact same game!  Imagine playing your game with a stack of coins, all of which are pennies except for the bottom coin, which is a quarter.  The rules allow you to pick up any square number of coins (from the top of the stack) that leave at least one coin.  Your game, which starts with $n$ coins, ends when only $1$ coin remains, namely the quarter; the other game starts with $n-1$ pennies, and ends when $0$ pennies remain.  That's why all the numbers are shifted by $1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thank you so much, i see it now !